# String Holding Array of objects?? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript

Can a String hold Array Object? May be this question could be silly? Just wanted to know...

Comment: Please kindly elaborate and explain why you would need such a thing.

Comment: A string is a string, an array an array. Both are different data types. What is your imagination of *a String holding Array Object* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string can just "hold" characters - that's what a String is.

Of course, those characters could denote a *stringified representation* of an array of objects, such as the string `[1, "two", MyCoolClass(5, 8.0)]`.  But that would just be some quasi-arbitrary encoding, and you'd have to do some work to convert it back again (see [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for a real-world example).

So the short answer is "no", but the real answer would be to ask for clarification of what it is you mean...

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot extend strings beyond adding methods to `String.prototype`.

For example:

```
> var x = 'foo'
  undefined
> x
  "foo"
> x.bar = 4
  4
> x
  "foo"
> x.bar
  undefined
```

Comment: You can if you use a string *object*: `var x = new String('foo')`. But of course this will create all sorts of other confusions/problems.

Comment: +1 @Felix; cannot agree strongly enough with the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

If you serialize (ie turn the object into a string) then yes a string can hold an array object. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, you could probably encode a set of objects into a string. Using JSON and a little bit of string acrobatics.

It would wind up looking like this

```
"{ field: var ... },...,{ field: var ... }"
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array referencing on strings, to access a specific letter:

```
a = "hello world"
a[0] // == 'h'
a[1] // == 'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.stringify(arrayToStringiFy)`

link to download the library [JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: The "library" is only needed on browsers that don't already support it. _Guess which browser that would be_